# Java array referencing another array

Tags: java, arrays

So is it possible to reference another array element from within a different array?

Like this

```
String[] array1 = new String[] {"World"};
String[] array2 = new String[] {"Hello", array1[0]};

array1[0] = "David";

for(String element : array2)
   System.out.print(element);
```

When I try to print the array, it just prints HelloWorld and not HelloDavid

Is this possible? If not, is this possible using variables?

Comment: Sound like you want something like C++...

Comment: Does this give you a hint : `String[] array1 = new String[] {"World"};
  String[] array2 = new String[] {"Hello", array1[0]};

  array1[0] = "David";
  array2[1] = array1[0]; 
  for(String element : array2)
     System.out.print(element);
 }`

Answer (score 7):

What you have is valid, but the output will be `HelloWorld`, not `HelloDavid`

Although `array1[0]` will have a new value, `array1` will be unaffected as it stores the String value reference, not the array reference, so when the array reference gets updated the Strings referenced in the array are no altered

**Edit**

Following on from your question what you're looking for is pointer functionality (as provided by C++).  The following multi-dimensional solution isn't exactly the same and its pretty clunky, but it would do what you wanted:

```
    String[] array1 = new String[]{"World"};
    String[][] array2 = new String[][]{new String[] {"Hello" }, array1};

    array1[0] = "David";

    for (String[] element : array2)
        System.out.print(element[0]);

    ==> output: HelloDavid
```

Comment: So is there a way to edit array1[0] and than print array2 with the updated array1[0]?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array2 = new String[] {"Hello", array1[0]};
```

In above code you are creating an array called `array2` whose `0th` index is containing the reference of `String literal` "Hello" and `1st` index is containing the reference of `String` literal("World") present in `StringPool` to which array1[0] is also referencing . According to [`JLS3.10.5-1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) `array2[1]` is changed by compiler as follows:

```
String[] array2 = new String[] {"Hello", "World"};
```

Now in line :

```
array1[0] = "David";
```

You make `array[0]` to contain the reference of the String "David" newly created in `StringPool`. But it is not going to change the element present at index `1` of `array2`. Since `array2[1]` is already referring to String literal "World" present in `StringPool`.
You  would have get "HelloDavid" output if you make following changes in your code:

```
array1[0] = "David";
array2[1] = array1[0];
```